# reassign a value in an array of objects in a loop does not work Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, foreach

I have an object `videos` and want to reassign every parameter `start` in it. for archiving this i looped through the object, but assigning only worked outside the loop, which seems strange to me.

I tried:

```js
var output1 = '';
let n=videos[0].start;
n = 0;

videos.forEach((element, index) => {
  videos[n].start = n * clipLength;
  output1 += n + ': ' + videos[n].start+'; ';
  n++;
});
console.log(output1);
```

That led to the result I wanted:

```
0: 0; 1: 2; 2: 4; 3: 6; 4: 8; 5: 10; 6: 12; 7: 14; 8: 16; 9: 18; 10: 20; 11: 22; 12: 24; 13: 26; 14: 28; 15: 30; 16: 32; 17: 34; 18: 36; 19: 38; 20: 40; 21: 42; 22: 44; 23: 46; 24: 48; 25: 50; 26: 52; 27: 54; 28: 56; 29: 58; 30: 60; 31: 62; 32: 64; 33: 66; 34: 68; 35: 70; 36: 72; 37: 74; 38: 76; 39: 78; 40: 80; 41: 82; 42: 84; 43: 86; 44: 88; 45: 90; 46: 92; 47: 94; 48: 96; 49: 98; 50: 100; 51: 102; 52: 104; 53: 106; 54: 108; 55: 110; 56: 112; 57: 114; 58: 116; 59: 118; 60: 120; 61: 122; 62: 124; 63: 126; 64: 128; 65: 130; 66: 132; 67: 134; 68: 136; 69: 138; 70: 140; 71: 142; 72: 144; 73: 146; 74: 148; 75: 150; 76: 152; 77: 154; 78: 156; 79: 158; 80: 160; 81: 162; 82: 164; 83: 166; 84: 168; 85: 170; 86: 172; 87: 174; 88: 176; 89: 178; 90: 180; 91: 182; 92: 184; 93: 186; 94: 188; 95: 190;
```

But when I check the result outside the loop I get my old values.

this:

```js
var output2 = '';

for (var property2 in videos) {
  output2 += property2 + ': ' + videos[property2].start+'; ';
}

console.log(output2);
```

led to:

```
0: 180; 1: 182; 2: 184; 3: 186; 4: 188; 5: 190; 6: 132; 7: 134; 8: 136; 9: 138; 10: 140; 11: 142; 12: 144; 13: 146; 14: 148; 15: 150; 16: 152; 17: 154; 18: 156; 19: 158; 20: 160; 21: 162; 22: 164; 23: 166; 24: 168; 25: 170; 26: 172; 27: 174; 28: 176; 29: 178; 30: 180; 31: 182; 32: 184; 33: 186; 34: 188; 35: 190; 36: 132; 37: 134; 38: 136; 39: 138; 40: 140; 41: 142; 42: 144; 43: 146; 44: 148; 45: 150; 46: 152; 47: 154; 48: 156; 49: 158; 50: 160; 51: 162; 52: 164; 53: 166; 54: 168; 55: 170; 56: 172; 57: 174; 58: 176; 59: 178; 60: 180; 61: 182; 62: 184; 63: 186; 64: 188; 65: 190; 66: 132; 67: 134; 68: 136; 69: 138; 70: 140; 71: 142; 72: 144; 73: 146; 74: 148; 75: 150; 76: 152; 77: 154; 78: 156; 79: 158; 80: 160; 81: 162; 82: 164; 83: 166; 84: 168; 85: 170; 86: 172; 87: 174; 88: 176; 89: 178; 90: 180; 91: 182; 92: 184; 93: 186; 94: 188; 95: 190;
```

Strangely enough the `videos[0].start = 0;` outside of the iteration works perfectly for me.

I tried several statements for the loops such as `for...in`, `for` or `forEach` with the same result, I couldn't change the videos object permanently.

What could be the reason and how can I change the `start` values?

**edit**

i tried to `Object.assign()` the `videos` object another way with no luck. could it be that it is because of the `Promise` Object, that doesn't let me change the values after creation?

here is the whole function (reduced to essentials):

```
 module.exports.submit = (data) => {
        const schema = {
            search: Joi.string().regex(/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/).min(2).max(30).required(),
            duration: Joi.number().integer().min(1).max(100).required()
        };

    const valid = Joi.validate({
        search: data.search,
        duration: data.duration
    }, schema);


    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const minClips = parseInt(data.duration/2);
        var maxClips = data.duration;
        const clipLength = 2;
        const videoStart = 0;

        pexelsClient.searchVideos(data.search, maxClips, 1).then(function(pexels) {

            let tracks = [];
            let videos = [];


            let x = Math.round(maxClips/(3/(maxClips/100))-1)
            console.log(x+" iterations")

            for (let [index, video] of pexels.videos.entries()) {
                let videoFiles = video.video_files;
                let hdVideo = videoFiles.find(file => file.height === 720 || file.height === 1920) || videoFiles[0];

                videos[index] = {
                    asset: {
                        type: "video",
                        src: hdVideo.link,
                        trim: Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)
                    },
                    start: (maxClips*2) - (index * clipLength),
                    length: clipLength, 
                    filter: "greyscale",
                    opacity: 0.3
                };


                if (index === 0) {
                    videos[index].transition = {
                        out: "fade"
                    }
                    console.log(index)
                }

                if (index === (maxClips - 1)) {
                    videos[index].transition = {
                        in: "fade"
                    }

                }

            }

            const videoslength = Object.keys(videos).length;

            console.log("asset "+videos[0].asset)

            var output1 = '';
            var n = 0;
            for (var i = 30; i <= videoslength; i++) {
                if (n >= 30) { n=0} else {
                    const b = Object.assign({}, videos, {


                            ...videos.asset,
                            asset: videos[n].asset

                    });
                    console.log(videos[n].asset)
                    }
                output1 += n + ': ' + videos[n].start+'; ';
                n++;
            }
            console.log(output1);
            console.log("amount elements "+Object.keys(videos).length);


            var output2 = '';
            for (var property2 in videos) {
                //videos[property2].start = property2 * clipLength;
                output2 += property2 + ': ' + videos[property2].asset.src+'; ';

            }
            console.log(output2);

            tracks[0] = {
                clips: videos
            };

            let timeline = {
                soundtrack: {
                    src: shotstackAssetsUrl + "music/" + data.soundtrack,
                    effect: "fadeOut"
                },
                background: "#000000",
                tracks: tracks,
            };

            let output = {
                format: "mp4",
                resolution: "sd"
            };

            let edit = {
                timeline: timeline,
                output: output
            };

            request({
                url: shotstackUrl + 'render',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'x-api-key': shotstackApiKey
                },
                json: true,
                body: edit
            }, function (error, response, body){
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    console.log(response);
                    return reject(error);
                }

                return resolve(body.response);
            });
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            return reject(error);
        });
    });
 };
```

Comment: Note that in your first snippet, `let n=videos[0].start;` is useless because you overwrite it just below: `n = 0;`

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of posting code in an answer

Answer (score 0):

Your code works (run the code below, you'll see the results), and once you've modified the value in your first loop (building output1), then the output2 is correct too.

But you have to call your first snippet (output1) first. The reason is that you actually modify the videos in your fist loop (`videos[n].start = n * clipLength;`) but not in your second loop, which simply checks the values.

Bottom line is, your code works, you may just not call it correctly.

```js
var videos = [{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}];
var clipLength = 2;

var output1 = '';
let n=videos[0].start;
n = 0;

videos.forEach((element, index) => {
    videos[n].start = n * clipLength;
    output1 += n + ': ' + videos[n].start+'; ';
    n++;
});
console.log(output1);

var output2 = '';
for (var property2 in videos) {
    output2 += property2 + ': ' + videos[property2].start+'; ';
}
console.log(output2);
```

Comment: thats the way it should work! but unfortunately i got the results as mentioned. i call it the same (right) order.

Comment: Can you share your full code or reproduce it somewhere (codepen, jsfiddle, or even directly stackoverflow, as I did in my answer) please ? Your error must be somewhere else since it's working in the answer.